# Align text parallel with a line

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I've been trying to draw triangles at weird angles in Canvas but I don't know how to align the text with the lines themselves. How would I go about doing this?

The code I'm using for a triangle is:

```html
 
 
function init()
{
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
if(canvas.getContext)
{
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100,100);
ctx.lineTo(200,50);
ctx.lineTo(300,40);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
}
}
onload=init;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

*To get you started...*

**Here's one way:**

1. Find the angle of the line using `Math.atan2`.

   ```
   // where x0,y0 is the line startpoint and x1,y1 is the endpoint
   var angle = Math.atan2( y1-y0, x1-x0 );
   ```
2. `context.translate(x0,y0)` to the starting point of the line.
3. `context.rotate(angle)` to the angle found in #1.
4. Set `context.textBaseline='bottom'` so text is drawn at the bottom of its baseline.
5. `context.fillText('Your text',0,0)` to draw the text along the angle of the line.
6. Undo the transformations with `context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)`.

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

ctx.textBaseline='bottom';

var x0=50;
var y0=100;
var x1=150;
var y1=50;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x0,y0);
ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);
ctx.stroke();

textOnLine('Hello, World!',x0,y0,x1,y1);

function textOnLine(text,x0,y0,x1,y1){
  var angle=Math.atan2(y1-y0,x1-x0);
  ctx.translate(x0,y0);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.fillText(text,0,0);
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```